# Describing sets using sets..

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is this kind of notation allowed?
I searched, but couldn't find this kind of notation.
Set is described using sets. I never saw this on the textbook.
If yes, what does it mean?
$\{x\mid x= 10^9a_1 + 10^8a_2 + 10^7a_3 + 10^6a_4 + 10^5a_5 + 10^4a_6 + 10^3a_7 + 10^2a_8 + 10a_9 + a_{10}\ ,\   \{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10}\}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\ ,\ \sqrt{x}\in\mathrm{N}\}$

Comment: Yes, perfectly correct. It simply describes natural numbers which are written in base $10$ with at most $10$ digits and are the square of another natural number.

Answer (score 1):

This set is representing all the integer numbers that can be written using each of the numbers $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ exactly once, whose square root is again a natural number. In other words all perfect squares that can be written as an anagram of $0123456789$.

This notation is allowed and is a common way to describe an implicitly defined set, i.e. a set which you can define via a rule (which can be a formula or also a phrase) without having to give an explicit formula for its elements or having to list them all.

Comment: Close, but the condition that $\{a_1,\dots,a_{10}\} = \{0,\dots,9\}$ implies even further that the number very specifically be ten digits with each digit occurring exactly once each or nine digits with each nonzero digit occurring exactly once each (*in the case that $a_1=0$*)

Comment: Absolutely! I hope my new answer is now correct.